# How to activate an optional dependency?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

**Cargo.toml:**

```rust
[features]
parallel = ["rayon"]

[dependencies.rayon]
version = "1.5"
optional = true
```

**lib.rs:**

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "parallel")]
pub mod par;
```

**Rust Analyzer:**

```
code is inactive due to #[cfg] directives: feature = "parallel" is disabled
```

***How to enable the optional dependency?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the Rust Analyzer configuration option `rust-analyzer.cargo.features` to an array containing a list of features that you want RA to consider active.

You can also set its value to "all", in order to enable all features in the project.

Methods for setting these vary according to the IDE you are using - for example, if using VS Code, you can set it via the "Extension Settings" for Rust Analyzer.

This assumes you are asking how to activate the features within Rust Analyzer - to activate them when building or running from Cargo, just use the `--features` option.

See: [Rust Analyzer Manual](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html)

Answer (score -1):

All non-default features need to be specified when running. So run with:

```sh
# Option 1
cargo run --features parallel
# Option 2
cargo run --all-features
```

Check `cargo run --help` for more help.