# rust-analyzer with optional feature

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I have vscode set up with the rust-analyzer plugin and it works in most cases. I have just added an optional feature but I cannot get vscode/rust-analyzer to parse the code, instead it always shows:

```
code is inactive due to #[cfg] directives: std is disabled rust-analyzer (inactive-code)
```

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
rand = {version = "0.8.5", default-features = false}

[features]
std = ["rand/std"]
```

main.rs:

```rust
#[cfg(std)]
use rand;

fn main() {}
```

My settings file has these lines:

```json
    "rust-analyzer.cargo.features": "all",
    "rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.features": "all"
```

I thought it might be related to using both a VSCode workspace and a cargo workspace but simplifying it down to a stub cargo project shows the same issue.

Finally, I followed the advice in this question (no other plugins running and enabled RA_LOGS) but the output appears to show the command I expect with `--all-features`: [How to activate an optional dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383494/how-to-activate-an-optional-dependency)

```
[INFO flycheck] restart flycheck "cargo" "check" "--workspace" "--message-format=json" "--manifest-path" "$HOME/workspace/stackoverflow/Cargo.toml" "--all-targets" "--all-features"
```

Any idea what else I can check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I realise I was using the wrong form for `cfg`. It should have been:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
```

In my real code I had a typo with the same effect `#[cfg(features = "std")]`